# Login with GNU screen with username and password in a script

Tags: scripting, gnu-screen, serial-port

I need to login to a screen session with `screen /dev/tty.usbmodem1415 115200` and then there is a prompt for `username` and `password`.

```
login:
Password:
```

After entering I would like to enter a simple command. E.g. `ls` and then exit the screen session.

Is there a way to script this entire process?

Comment: `expect` can do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks! Found the answer

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set username "hello"
set password "secret"
spawn screen /dev/tty.usbmodem1415 115200

expect "?ogin:"
send "$username\r"

expect "?assword:"
send "$password\r"

send "ls\r"
```

Comment: You may accept your own answer if you are satisfied with it